# Compressor PDF file using C#

Tags: c#, pdf, reduce

I have a request for reduce PDF file size in code level if u have a solution please share with me.

But image size should be lowest.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Comment: I want to comperes PDF file size. converting like image file.

Answer (score 2):

The following code example demonstrates how to compress a PDF document by reducing/compressing the qualities of images in the document. You can give it a try.

```
//Loads the PDF document
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument("Image.pdf");
//Disables the incremental update
doc.FileInfo.IncrementalUpdate = false;

//Traverses all pages
foreach (PdfPageBase page in doc.Pages)
{
    //Extracts images from page
    Image[] images = page.ExtractImages();
    if (images != null && images.Length > 0)
    {
        //Traverses all images
        for (int j = 0; j < images.Length; j++)
        {
            Image image = images[j];
            PdfBitmap bp = new PdfBitmap(image);
            //Reduces the quality of the image
            bp.Quality = 20;
            //Replaces the old image in the document with the compressed image
            page.ReplaceImage(j, bp);
        }
    }                
}
//Saves and closes the resultant document
doc.SaveToFile("Output.pdf");
doc.Close();
```

Note: This example is offered by Spire.PDF and I'm an employee of Spire. You can check the [How to Compress PDF Document in C#, VB.NET](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDF/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide/Document-Operation/How-to-Compress-PDF-Document-in-C-VB.NET.html) article for detailed information.